# How to Use Datepicker Gem

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm sure this is a very trivial question, but I'm having trouble getting setup with the [datepicker gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails). I added it to my Gemfile, ran bundle install, added a line to my application.css and to my application.js. However, when I edit the view, I get a text input box, but it doesn't pop-up the calendar the way it's supposed to. I have the feeling I must be overlooking something simple here. If anyone can take a look and help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

application.css

```
/*
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 */

th,
td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

And finally my view, new.html.erb

```
<h1>Projects#new</h1>
<h1>Create a new project</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/projects/new.html.erb</p>

<input type="text" class='datepicker' >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Turbolinks (a gem that Rails 4 includes in your Gemfile by default) causes some issues with `$(document).ready(function() {` such that it doesn't always trigger. Could you try switching it out with `$(document).on("page:change", function() {` and check if that helps?

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. Still no calendar popup.

Comment: Think I figured it out. I installed this gem exactly as you have it written here, and I found that it wouldn't work unless I moved `//= require bootstrap-datepicker` under `\\= require jquery`.

Comment: The order of your directives in `application.js` and `application.css` actually matter. You have to make sure to load dependencies first, otherwise, you're not going to have much luck trying to get dependent libraries loaded. In addition to what @februaryInk pointed out, it's likely you'll need to make sure the `bootstrap` gem is referenced.

Comment: Thank you! TIL that the order matters.